# How to call a connectivityCheck method from a connectivity class file ? [Android]

Tags: android, performance, nullpointerexception

How to call a connectivityCheck method from a connectivity class file ? [Android]

For example, the code @ the connectivity class file

```
public class ConnectivityMgr {
 /*
 *@return boolean return true if the application can access the internet
 */
 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
     ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
           for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
              if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                 return true;
              }
           }
        }
     }
     return false;
  }
}
```

What do i have to do to call this method from the class, for example if its under a package called final.last.test

Do i have to import the class file and declare or something like that, i tried using

```
if ( isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext()) == true ) {}
```

and it gives me a `NullPointerException`. Was it the wrong use of "getApplicationContext()" or something else?

I tried importing, declaring .. , changing to this.getApplicationContext() / this / getBaseContext() and it still doesn't work.

Or does it require an "Intent" ?

What i did was:

```
import final.last.test.ConnectivityMgr; 
ConnectivityMgr cm; 

try { 

if ( cm.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext() ) 
{ //display yes } 

} Catch as (Exception e) 
{ Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error with connectivity : " + e.getCause() + " , " + e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

// Log.d("Error With Connectivity : ","Failed to do something due to : " + e.getMessage());
```

-> The Log never show up before, that is why i used toast instead.

-> Toast shows " Error With Connectivity :  null , java.lang , NullPointerException –

Comment: ConnectivityMgr.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext()) and imprt "package of ConnectivityMgr".ConnectivityMgr.Show logcat output if you still have errors.

Comment: What i did was...

import final.last.test.ConnectivityMgr;
ConnectivityMgr cm;
try
{
if ( cm.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext() )
{
//display yes
}
}
Catch as (Exception e)
  {
   
   
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error with connectivity : " + e.getCause() + " , " + e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // Log.d("Error With Connectivity : ","Failed to do something due to : " + e.getMessage());

 -> The Log never worked for me.
        -> Toast shows " null , java.lang , NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        boolean mBoolean = false;
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        mBoolean = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return mBoolean;
    }
```

then

```
if ( isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {}
```

Comment: // Question-er edit
// import (package).(class file);
// classfile cf;
// if ( cf.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {}


// however, i used try catch and caught the nullpointexception.

Answer (score 0):

```
        URL myurl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = myurl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(20 * 1000);
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            httpConnection.disconnect();
            //......

        }
        else
        {
            httpConnection.disconnect();
            throw new Exception(
                    "Http Error code: " + String.valueOf(responseCode));
        }
```